# How to create maven dependency that contains only xml files?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am creating maven project using java, hibernate and mySql. I have one module called persistence module that contains all hibernate configuration. How can I make this module as a maven dependency to use by another module and how to use this dependency?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have this module structure: persistence/person.hbm.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml, pom.xml. I am not sure if I can make this as a module and what packaging type to use in the pom.xml file

Comment: You can put those XML files into src/main/resources and a standard jar type - and it'll put those files into a JAR.  Is that what you want?

Comment: How will the other module use the XML files?  Or, more to the point, how will it locate them (e.g. as a class-path resource, or loading by file path)?

Comment: I see. How can I access those files in another module?

Comment: So these are really deployment files?  In other words - they will only be used at runtime, once the application is installed?

Comment: If you're not sure how they will be accessed, how about showing the code, or other reference, that is expected to use those files?